# What's the point of view parameter of translation(in:) func of UIPanGestureRecognizer?

Tags: ios, uipangesturerecognizer

Better late than never.

UIPanGestureRecognizer has a [translation(in:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipangesturerecognizer/1621207-translation) func with view parameter. Does someone know why it parameter there?

I've tried different values of this parameter - nil, window, superview, view but the func always returns the same value. Is there some case when it different?

Regarding apple documentation view parameter is *The view in whose coordinate system the translation of the pan gesture should be computed.* So, what does it mean?

Just in case it works fine. Usually I use view as a parameter that has pan gesture but I want to know:)

**UPD:** Same situation with [velocity(in:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipangesturerecognizer/1621209-velocity) parameter of UIPanGestureRecognizer.

Comment: Usually you want the translation in the view the gesture is attached to.. sometimes that view's bounds may be outside of the window's bounds.. sometimes there may be a sub-view that is smaller than the pan gesture's view.. translation in the smaller sub-view will be scaled down compared to in the original larger view. If two views don't have the same bounds and stuff, it might return a different value as it will transform the vector from one view to another.. Possibly via: `[convertRect:toView:]` or `[convertPoint:toView:]`

Comment: @Brandon It's exactly how I firstly understand it. But if you try views from different hierarchy as func translation(in:) parameter it will return the same value. Later I want to try with the different uiwindow and uiscreen may be it's a point.

Comment: @Brandon, Thanks for using the word `vector`.  I was perplexed by how you could move a view to the correct location by adding `translation.x` and `translation.y`,  to the existing x,y coordinates of a view, when the docs say that `translation` is, "***A point identifying the new location of a view***".   For instance, if something is at `(1, 1)` and it moves to `(2,2)`, it's new location is not `(1+2,1+2)` = `(3,3)`-- it's `(2,2)`.   But if translation is a *vector*, then the translation represents the absolute change in the x coord and y coord of the gesture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're not seeing any difference is that a point is a point for all the views you've checked.

But now add to your interface a view whose `transform` is a CGAffineTransform scale transform and use *that* to check the value of `translation(in:)`. You'll see a difference!

So you can see why specifying the view might matter. This whole thing could be taking place in a world (or a portion of the world) to which a scale transform has been applied, and in that case you'd want the answer in an appropriate point scale.